# JMSSerializer: Use id to retrieve related object from database

Tags: json, doctrine-orm, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Using Symfony 3 I have written an entity that is supposed to be exposed via JSON / JMSSerializer (in a RESTful manner). It looks like this:

```
/**
 * MainEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="MainEntity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 */
 class MainEntity{

   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
   private $id;

   //... some more "simple" fields ...

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SubEntity")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subentity", referencedColumnName="id")
   * })
   * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getSubEntityId",setter="setSubEntity")
   * @JMS\Type("integer")
   * @JMS\SerializedName("subEntityId")
   */
   private $subEntity;
   //...

   public function getSubEntityId() {
       return $this->subEntity->getId();
   }

}
```

JSON serialization of the whole thing works like a charm! Especially, only the subentity ID is exposed, instead of the whole sub entity, which can be quite large.

So instead of:

```
{"id": 1, ..., "subEntity": {"id": 123, "name": "Great subEntity", ...} }
```

I get

```
{"id": 1, ..., "subEntityId": 123 }
```

which is perfectly what I neet.

But when it comes to **de**serialization, I get in trouble... Of course I want to use the shortened JSON format also on incoming requests, but this fails, because `setSubEntity` expects a `SubEntity` instance and not a number.

Is there any way I can achieve the deserialization to retrieve the related object when the ID is given?

I thought about these possibilities:

1. Use a special setter (given in the `@JMS\Accessor` annotation), taking the id and populating the `subEntity` field with the object retrieved from the database. But this would mean to inject the EntityManager into the Entity (or something similar and bad...)
2. Add a new numeric field `subEntityId` and get it populated by a special setter (like above). Then use the controller to read it, get the `SubEntity` object from the database and use the `setSubEntity` method *after* the entity was deserialized. Doesn't look that nice to me too...

Any suggestions? I see, there are some similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but it seems to me, that no one is describing my special case.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to create extra fields or setters. Possible approach is creating your own [Serializer handler](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers) and using it in mapping.

I've already answered [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051659/jmsserializer-deserialize-entity-by-id) so you could get the code sample there.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your services configuration, here I write it in YAML

```
jms_serializer.object_constructor:
    alias: jms_serializer.initialized_object_constructor
    public: false

jms_serializer.initialized_object_constructor:
    class: MyApp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Serializer\InitializedObjectConstructor
    arguments: ["@jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor"]
```

Add this class for `jms_serializer.initialized_object_constructor`

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Serializer;
use JMS\Serializer\VisitorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\Construction\ObjectConstructorInterface;
class InitializedObjectConstructor implements ObjectConstructorInterface
{
    private $fallbackConstructor;
    public function __construct(ObjectConstructorInterface $fallbackConstructor)
    {
        $this->fallbackConstructor = $fallbackConstructor;
    }
    public function construct(VisitorInterface $visitor, ClassMetadata $metadata, $data, array $type, DeserializationContext $context)
    {
        if ($context->attributes->containsKey('target') && $context->getDepth() === 1) {
            return $context->attributes->get('target')->get();
        }
        return $this->fallbackConstructor->construct($visitor, $metadata, $data, $type, $context);
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
protected function flushRequestData(Request $request, $entity = null)
{
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager');
    $context = new DeserializationContext();
    if ($entity) {
        $context->attributes->set('target', $entity);
    }

    $deserializedObj = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
        $data,
        $this->getRepository()->getClassName(),
        'json',
        $context
    );

    // After deserialized into your entity you need to manually set each of the related entity one by one manually
}
```