# Adding custom serializer handler makes attribute not exposed

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Using Symfony with JMS Serializer I was trying to achieve the same result as the question here: [JMSSerializer deserialize entity by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051659/jmsserializer-deserialize-entity-by-id)

Which is to send an integer (foreign key) instead of a whole object into my json-api to add a relation to an existing object when creating another object.

This is working as expected but using the @Type annotation with a custom type (copied from the question linked above) seems to override the @Groups annotation so that the related object is not visible in the api anymore. Even though the @Groups annotation is suppose to expose it.

Why is it so? How do I resolve it?

```
/**
 * @var SubObj
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SubObj", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sub_obj_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Groups({"show_this_attr"})
 * @Type("Entity<AppBundle\Entity\SubObj>")
 * @Inline
 */
private $subObj;
```